# gitlab pipeline build server for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, devops, gitlab-ci

We're running everything in AWS, including our self-hosted Gitlab server.
Now I am trying to create a pipeline to build and publish our IOS apps. Gitlab cloud does offer MacOS runner, but we're not planning to migrate it to the cloud in short term.
So I am looking for a MacOS server on cloud. AWS does offer dedicated mac servers, but they are limited to certain regions and are really expensive. I don't need a 6 core mac server. Maybe a 2 core server should be enough as we're probably going to build and publish the apps once a month. A mac mini running somewhere would be enough. But I'd prefer not to host it myself. Is there a good cloud provider that offers mac servers. Or any SAAS pipeline can achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of seeking out a cloud provider of macOS servers, configure one or more GitLab runners on your own equipment.

See:

- [Setting up GitLab CI for iOS Projects](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/)
- [How to publish iOS apps to the App Store with GitLab and fastlane](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/03/06/ios-publishing-with-gitlab-and-fastlane/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying Odevio, which is really an virtual iOS provider, than a full cloud providedr. It's is free for limited usage